# distributed alpha beta pruning

Tags: search, tree

I am looking for an efficient algorithm that lets me process the minimax search tree for chess with alpha-beta pruning on a distributed architecture. The algorithms I have found (PVS, YBWC, DTS) are all quite old (1990 being the latest). I assume there have been many substantial advancements since then. What is the current standard in this field?

Also please point me to an idiot's explanation of DTS as I can't understand it from the research papers that I have read.

Comment: you mean I should ask this guy and post this question on that forum?

Comment: have you found anything useful?

Comment: the project was cancelled and its almost been a year so I don't remember much. I did conclude that distributed architecture did not give a lot of improvement in my scenario. The overhead was too much. I had figured out that it was better for me implement the algorithm in a non distributed architecture with a clever set of heuristics.

Comment: thanks a lot for explaining your experiences.